# Laravel Database query. User information

Tags: mysql, laravel

```js
  @foreach($users as $user)
     <div>
        {{ $user->username }}
     </div>
  @endforeach
```

```html
  public function group($id){

        if (!$this->secure($id) && $this->secure($id)) return redirect('/404');

        $user = Auth::user();
        $hobbies = Hobby::all();
        $group = $this->group;

        $users = DB::table('users')
                ->join('user_hobbies', 'users.id', '=', 'user_hobbies.user_id')
                ->where('user_hobbies.hobby_id' == $group_id)
                ->select('users.*')->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC');
        
        $users = $users->get();
        
        $wall = [
            'new_post_group_id' => $group->id
        ];

        return view('groups.group', compact('user', 'users', 'group','wall', 'hobbies'));
    }
```

Hey guys, complete beginner here.. Im trying to access and return the users information of the members of a group. I am not so sure where I am going wrong and I'm trying to understand the log instructions but I can't quite understand where I'm going wrong. Ive seen "Sql error column doesn't exist in where clause".. tried to change the code and finding undeclared variables too.
The system is that a user creates a hobby and that hobby becomes the group. ie 'my hobby is skiing and then a group of skiing is created'. So I have a user_hobbies model of course and everything is work, but I can't quite work out how to access the information of the user from the DB and display it in the blade.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo on query builder.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_hobbies', 'users.id', '=', 'user_hobbies.user_id')
            ->where('user_hobbies.hobby_id' == $group_id) // This line
            ->select('users.*')->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC');
```

It should be

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_hobbies', 'users.id', '=', 'user_hobbies.user_id')
            ->where('user_hobbies.hobby_id', $group_id)
            ->select('users.*')->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC');
```

And make sure you use === instead of == for explicit comparation in PHP. It will cause a [Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). **I assume your blade file is correct since i dont know what's inside the $user object**

Comment: Thank you, I'm not returning any errors anymore but my blade is not returning anything either! I'm guessing the object is incorrect?

Comment: just dd($users) to get all property from $users, then just pass it to query